# Should I use mainnet node provided by infura or create my own?

Tags: go-ethereum, infura, ethernodes

I am trying to implement a solution in my current system where payments can be made via ethereum main network. I have done some research and found out that I have two options of implementation:

1. Use node provided by infura.
2. Create and maintain my own node with go Ethereum client and connect with mainnet through it.

   I just want to conduct transactions with this node. I don't need to implement custom smart contracts.

I know that the first option is a lot less work but is it reliable? Can I depend for all my transactions on the provided node?

What would be the advantages or disadvantages of both?

Comment: My question is different because I want to know whether it is a good idea to base my system on infura node? Is it reliable enough and what would be the optimal approach in this case.

Comment: it's the same thing. Why your own node instead of infura? If you fully trust infura, then it's ok for you to use it otherwise just have your own node. The duplicate really answers your question. It's not specific to infura. Any tier node will require you to trust it.

Comment: That is the part of the question, is infura node reliable enough for me to trust it?

Comment: this is opinion related. If this is really your question, then I'm sorry but we have to close it.